# Is there some way to get a pleasant human voice to speak to me on Windows without paying money, from a terminal command?

Tags: windows-10, text-to-speech-voices

Please note that I've plowed in hundreds of combined hours into trying to find a solution, so I'm not looking for "search results advice" here. Please only respond if you have personal, recent/current experience with this tool.

I'm trying to find a free program which lets me run it like this on the command line:

```
whatever.exe "Speak this text."
```

And which sounds like a human. Preferably female.

The built-in Windows "voices" are locked out from non-Microsoft software.

eSpeak has robotic voices only.

No existing Stack Whatever question has a single satisfactory answer, nor any question anywhere else which I've been able to find.

There seems to exist payware, but I'm not made of money and it's always impossible to pay them anonymously (= securely) anyway.

In spite of spending so much time and energy on this, I've never found anything at all. It doesn't seem to exist. You'd think this would be built into Windows, since it actually has a bunch of great-sounding voices which I'm not allowed to use even though they are on my computer.

Comment: I've seen malware webpages speak from Internet Explorer (or maybe Edge or Chrome) so I suspect you can tap into this Microsoft voices. There appears to be API's & sample code have you looked at that (link at end)? While not as simple of a command as you requested, beggars can't be choosers. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/speech

Comment: See [Unlock all Windows 10 TTS voices system-wide to get more of them](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/08/11/unlock-all-windows-10-tts-voices-system-wide-to-get-more-of-them/).

Answer (score 1):

Open PowerShell ISE & paste the below ([taken from this site](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-text-to-speech-examples/)):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.Speak('Hello...')
```

Comment: To choose the voice : [SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice(String) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice?view=netframework-4.8).